# How to create a usable scroll with ncurses C

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

This basic program takes the contents of a file and displays it. Also with `wsetscrreg()` I have created a scroll section, all works perfectly, but the problem is that when I scroll and the text gets out of the screen it disappears completely, and that's not how a scroll works. I'm reading the docs but I dont have any clue on why it does this.

```c
#include "window.h"
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

WINDOW *
new_window (char *file)
{
    WINDOW *win;
    int start_x, start_y;

    getmaxyx (stdscr, start_y, start_x);
    win = newwin (start_y, start_x - 2, 1, 1);
    mvprintw (1, 3, "%s", file);
    scrollok (win, TRUE);
    wsetscrreg (win, 0, start_y);
    box (win, 0, 0);
    wrefresh (win);
    refresh ();
    return win;
}
void
init_window ()
{
    initscr ();
    cbreak ();
    noecho ();
    start_color ();
    curs_set (0);
    init_pair (1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
    refresh ();
}
void
end_window (WINDOW *win)
{
    delwin (win);
    endwin ();
}
// "█"
//

void
load_file (WINDOW *win, char *path, int max_x)
{
    FILE *f;
    char c;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    f = fopen (path, "r");

    if (f == NULL)
        {
            mvwprintw (win, 0, 0,
                       "Error: File not found or cannot be opened.");
            wrefresh (win);
            return;
        }

    while ((c = fgetc (f)) != EOF)
        {

            if (c == '\n')
                {
                    y++;
                    x = 0;
                }
            else if (x > max_x - 5)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    y++;
                    mvwprintw (win, y, x, "%c", c);
                }
            else if (c != '\n')
                {

                    mvwprintw (win, y, x, "%c", c);
                }

            x++;
        }

    fclose (f);
    wrefresh (win);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    WINDOW *win;
    int max_y, max_x, scrollPos = 0;
    char ch;

    init_window ();
    win = new_window (argv[1]);
    getmaxyx (win, max_y, max_x);

    load_file (win, argv[1], max_x);

    while ((ch = wgetch (win)) != 'q')
        {
            if (ch == 'j')
                {
                    wscrl (win, 1);
                }
            if (ch == 'k')
                {
                    wscrl (win, -1);
                }
        }

    end_window (win);
    return 0;
}
```

I think that one solution could be working with some buffers displaying and deleting lines one by one when the user scrolls, but that implementation seems much more complex than the actual problem, and I think that the answer is very simple compared to that.

Comment: The terminal emulator only keeps scrollback when you let it scroll normally. When you use ncurses to emulate scrolling, it just overwrites the screen, so there's no scrollback buffer.

Comment: The simple approach uses a **pad** (see [related q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ncurses+pad+scroll)).